# Finding affine transformations to make two shapes similar

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Suppose we have two convex polygons, namely A and B, whose positions of vertices are given. We apply some affine transformations so that

1) A and B are as similar as possible, and

2) A contains B.

Questions:

1) How can I find such a transformation?

2) What if we restrict transformations to rotations, scalings, translations, and optionally, reflections?

(The numbers of vertices of A and B need not to be the same.)

Comment: There are many different possible measures of similarity. Did you have a particular measure in mind? (E.g., given the requirement that `A` contains `B`, you might want to maximise the ratio `area(B)/area(A)`. But that's just one possibility.)

Comment: If you use simple squared distances, solving (1) will become a simple linear least squares problem. If you restrict yourself to rigid body transforms, you can solve the problem with Kabsch's algorithm. There are also extensions that allow scalings. However, the second constraint is pretty hard (non-continuous). You will probably need an approximation for that in order to find a solution in a reasonable time.

Comment: @NicoSchertler The numbers of vertices of A and B do not have to be necessarily equal, and therefore simple squared distances are not suitable. Is there a distance measure that works under this condition?

Comment: @MarkDickinson Currently I don't have a particular measure of similarity in mind. Two shapes are "similar" as long as they "look similar".

Comment: Then Hausdorff distance might be suitable. Though, also pretty hard to optimize due to its discontinuous derivative..